# rails and uploadify nested_attributes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uploadify

I have a form for a model which has many photos and it all works fine thru the form using the nested_attributes feature in the places model.

The form for is like this:

```
<% form_for @place, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

And produces in html

This:

```
<form method="post" id="edit_place_6933" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/places/some-record" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

But when I start using uploadify it takes a script path as a param which I gave

```
<%= place_path(@place) %>
```

or

```
/places/some-record
```

by post, the same location as generated by the form_for

However this always returns:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/places/some-record...
```

Despite the fact that both the form_for (successful) and the uploadify script both start with this in the log

```
Started POST "/places/some-record" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 03 13:09:42 +0100 2010
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your log says "Started **POST**". Are you sure, you're calling `/places/some-record` as a POST-Request? Otherwise you have to allow more Method-Types.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a PUT method. So add PUT method accept on this route.